Save file to server using node js express
I'm not sure how to save a file type to the server I'm on in node. Here is my goal:
There will an array of objects that I will need to access in the backend, and save files in those objects based on certain conditions so I'd like to avoid using forms, or a middleware that only allows a file upload.


I updated the images to clarify what I'm looking for a bit better.
Update:
I figured out I can convert files to array buffers on the client side and save that on node. I tried sending the file as a variable to node and converting it to a buffer there to save but this did not work. For whatever reason, I have to convert it before sending. I'll just add another property called "arrayBuffer" to objects that have files. I should also note that on the client I have to run npm install buffer and import it (even though VS code already recognized it)



It's unclear what you're trying to avoid here.  To upload a file via http, the client has to create the proper content-type that can hold the file's data and the file's contents have to be encoded properly for that.  If the client is a browser, that's all done for you by specifying the file in a form and then you need code (usually set up as middleware) that can decode that file's data.  So, apparently, you're trying to avoid the easy way to do this which has us confused.

I think there's a good chance I just have a poor understanding of how this interaction works haha. Basically I have an array of objects, and want to send the array to the backend. I then loop through the array and do like a bunch of SQL queries. I want to, during every iteration of the loop, be able to upload files inside of the object. Doing a bunch of file uploads from the client seems like a bad idea. Is there a way I can do an http post, and then during each iteration of the loop call the middleware to upload the file? I could also programmatically turn each file into a form and send that?

Should I make a new formdata for each file and change the object to have the FormData data type instead of File?

Edited version
try this
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Middleware to handle raw data
app.use('/uploadFile', (req, res, next) => {
  let data = [];
  req.on('data', chunk => {
    data.push(chunk);
  });
  req.on('end', () => {
    if (req.headers['content-length'] > 10485760) { // 10 MB limit
      res.status(413).send('File size exceeds limit');
      return;
    }
    req.rawBody = Buffer.concat(data);
    next();
  });
});

app.post('/uploadFile', async (req, res) => {
  const fileData = req.rawBody;
  const originalFileName = req.headers['x-file-name'];
  const fileName = path.basename(originalFileName); // Avoid path traversal
  const fileExtension = path.extname(fileName).toLowerCase();

  // Only allow certain file extensions
  if (!['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.txt'].includes(fileExtension)) {
    res.status(400).send('Invalid file type');
    return;
  }

// do you own validation logics, my code is just to give an example.


  const savePath = path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', fileName);

  try {
    if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'))) {
      fs.mkdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'), { recursive: true });
    }

    fs.writeFileSync(savePath, fileData);
    res.send({ message: "File uploaded successfully" });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Failed to upload file", error: error.message });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});


How to call this from client
@Colin There are many ways to call this,
If you are using HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
<button onclick="uploadFile()">Upload</button>

<script>
function uploadFile() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/uploadFile", true);
    
    // Set appropriate headers
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", file.name);
    
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            alert('File uploaded successfully');
        } else {
            alert('File upload failed');
        }
    };
    
    xhr.send(file);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

if you are using curl
curl -X POST -H "X-File-Name: filename.jpg" --data-binary @/path/to/your/file.jpg http://localhost:3000/uploadFile


Be careful with this code... there are significant potential security issues here.  You're allowing the user to specify the path they want to write to, which could be ../../../something-dangerous... allowing them to traverse the whole file system, upload executables, overwrite configurations, etc.

How would I call this on the client, assuming the file is a property of an object?
